# Is it possible to include a C# variable in a string variable without using a concatenator?

Tags: c#, string, .net-3.5, string-interpolation

Does .NET 3.5 C# allow us to include a variable within a string variable without having to use the + concatenator (or string.Format(), for that matter).

For example (In the pseudo, I'm using a $ symbol to specify the variable):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
string s = "The date is $d";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

> The date is 4/12/2011 11:56:39 AM

**Edit**

Due to the handful of responses that suggested string.Format(), I can only assume that my original post wasn't clear when I mentioned "*...(or string.Format(), for that matter)*". To be clear, I'm well aware of the string.Format() method. However, in my specific project that I'm working on, string.Format() doesn't help me (it's actually worse than the + concatenator).

Also, I'm inferring that most/all of you are wondering what the motive behind my question is (I suppose I'd feel the same way if I read my question as is).

If you are one of the curious, here's the short of it:

I'm creating a web app running on a Windows CE device. Due to how the web server works, I create the entire web page content (css, js, html, etc) within a string variable. For example, my .cs managed code might have something like this:

```
string GetPageData()
    {
    string title = "Hello";
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

    string html = @"
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>$title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>Hello StackO</div>
    <div>The date is $date</div>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

}
```

As you can see, having the ability to specify a variable without the need to concatenate, makes things a bit easier - especially when the content increases in size.

Comment: What do you have against the a concatenator exactly?  What did the poor little plus sign every do to you?  All its life its stuck doing the exact samething at least you can do is use it.

Comment: @Ramhound - Ha! I mean no disrespect to the poor little plus sign. For the motive behind my question, read my response to @conqenator.

Comment: The idea is not bad but I would never do it. As soon as you rename your variables it wouldn't work any more.

Comment: @t3chb0t - if refactoring handles it well, then no worries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost, with a small extension method.

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string PHPIt<T>(this string s, T values, string prefix = "$")
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        foreach(var p in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            sb = sb.Replace(prefix + p.Name, p.GetValue(values, null).ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

And now we can write:

```
string foo = "Bar";
int cool = 2;

var result = "This is a string $foo with $cool variables"
             .PHPIt(new { 
                    foo, 
                    cool 
                });

//result == "This is a string Bar with 2 variables"
```

Answer (score 12):

No, unfortunately C# is not PHP.
On the bright side though, C# is not PHP.

Comment: Fortunately, C# is taking the best from PHP :) String interpolation is now available in C#6.0 and Visual Basic 14.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. There are ways around this, but they defeat the purpose. Easiest thing for your example is

```
Console.WriteLine("The date is {0}", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string output = "the date is $d and time is $t";
output = output.Replace("$t", t).Replace("$d", d);  //and so on
```

Comment: "without having to use [...] string.Format()"

Comment: As to your question. No. But I'm curious why you want it that way.

Comment: I'm creating web app running on a Windows CE device. Long story short, I create the entire web page content (css, js, html) within a string variable. As you can imagine, the string var gets pretty ugly with all the + concats for including my variables within the string var. It would make my life a bit easier if we could use the PHP/ColdFusion inline syntax.

Comment: You could use place holders such as `#variablename` (like in your question) and then use` string.replace()`?..

Comment: @Jed that sounds like an entirely different question. You should probably be using a StringBuilder. Having long strings like that could possibly pollute the LOH.

Comment: @RobinMaben - many languages are equipped with 'variable inside string' feature. I would use this for building easy-to-read SQL commands as this is much more readable than parametrized queries. (No worries,security is handled.) So suggested `replace()` is not an equivalent of what is given in accepted answer – imagine expression followed by 5 Replace's compared to simple `"my string".PHPIt(New {a, b, c, d, e})` without any extra code. This is also safer, you cannot accidentally mix order of parameters (as with {0}, {1}); also you can throw FixMe exception if param is not in string etc... :)

Comment: @miroxlav: Using **`Razor Views`** would solve the OP's right away I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the great answer of @JesperPalm I found another interesting solution which let's you use a similar syntax like in the normal `string.Format` method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Replace<T>(this string text, T values)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(text);
        var properties = typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .ToArray();

        var args = properties
            .Select(p => p.GetValue(values, null))
            .ToArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            var oldValue = string.Format("{{{0}", properties[i].Name);
            var newValue = string.Format("{{{0}", i);

            sb.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
        }

        var format = sb.ToString();

        return string.Format(format, args);
    }
}
```

This gives you the possibility to add the usual formatting:

```
var hello = "Good morning";
var world = "Mr. Doe";
var s = "{hello} {world}! It is {Now:HH:mm}."
    .Replace(new { hello, world, DateTime.Now });

Console.WriteLine(s); // -> Good morning Mr. Doe! It is 13:54.
```

Comment: I see added value here in enabling `string.format()` format specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The short and simple answer is: No!

Comment: Albeit a bit too simple. It _is_ short.

Comment: Why is it too simple? All other answers obviously ignore, that the author has excluded Format and similar functions.

Comment: Technically the answer is oversimplified when considering how easily requested feature can be built (see the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("The date is {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString())
```

Comment: Why have extra code? Especially considering this is a question and answer site. Someone will copy you, and a whole lot more people will have to deal with it.

Comment: It does save on boxing the DateTime

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: Converting the value to string avoids boxing. If you don't do it explicitly, it will be done implicitly, so it's no extra code created. Sometimes it's better to show what the code is doing with actual source code instead of making the compiler create the same code implicitly. All in all, it's no clear cut case where one way is clearly better than the other.

Comment: If only reflector was still free so I could see if it is boxing or not for sure.

Comment: @Brandon: _"@Guffa - thank you. I wasn't going to respond..."__ -- you know that's what the 'up' arrow icons are for <grin/> @Yuriy: monodis/ildasm will show it is (`IL_000b:  ldloc.0 ; IL_000c:  box [mscorlib]System.DateTime`)

Comment: @yuriy faktorovich - check out ILSpy

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: The `String.Format` method only takes the type `object` for the data parameters, so any value type has to be boxed to be sent to the method.

Comment: The OP does not want to use `.Format`

Answer (score 0):

No, But you can create an extension method on the string instance to make the typing shorter.

```
string s = "The date is {0}".Format(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.Format` (and similar formatting functions such as `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`) are the best way to do this in terms of flexibility, coding practice, and (usually) performance:

```
string s = string.Format("The date is {0}", d);
```

You can also specify the display format of your DateTime, as well as inserting more than one object into the string. Check out [MSDN's page on the string.Format method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx).

Certain types also have overloads to their `ToString` methods which allow you to specify a format string. You could also create an extension method for `string` that allows you to specify a format and/or parse syntax like this.

Comment: check [this asnwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23541040/2392157) on solution how to achieve what OP requested while keeping syntax of **String.Format** like `{0:HH:mm}` (in that case `{Now:HH:mm}`)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the T4 templating engine?

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/05/01/visual-studios-t4-code-generation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to avoid concatenation of immutable strings, what you're looking for is [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Usage:

```
string parameterName = "Example";
int parameterValue = 1;
Stringbuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("The output parameter ");
builder.Append(parameterName);
builder.Append("'s value is ");
builder.Append(parameterValue.ToString());
string totalExample = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **C# 6.0** you can write string `"The title is \{title}"` which does exactly what you need.

Comment: Does C# 6.0 support refactoring for such strings as well? Otherwise it's pretty dangerous to hardcode the variable name inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this as mentioned in C# documentation.
**string interpolation**

```
string name = "Horace";
int age = 34;
Console.WriteLine($"He asked, \"Is your name {name}?\", but didn't wait for a reply :-{{");
Console.WriteLine($"{name} is {age} year{(age == 1 ? "" : "s")} old.");
```

Answer (score -1):

Or combined:

```
Console.WriteLine("The date is {0}", DateTime.Now);
```

Extra info (in response to [BrandonZeider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640223/is-it-possible-to-include-a-c-variable-in-a-string-variable-without-using-a-conc/5640241#5640241)):

Yep, it is kind-a important for people to realize that string conversion is automatically done. Manually adding ToString is broken, e.g.:

```
string value = null;
Console.WriteLine("The value is '{0}'", value); // OK
Console.WriteLine("The value is '{0}'", value.ToString()); // FAILURE
```

Also, this becomes a lot less trivial once you realize that the stringification is **not equivalent to using .ToString()**. You can have format specifiers, and even custom format format providers... It is interesting enough to teach people to leverage String.Format instead of doing it manually.

Comment: There is nothing that says that the formatting *should* always be able to handle a null value. If the value is not supposed to be null, there is no added value in handling the case where it's null.

Comment: Dude...get over it. DateTime.Now cannot be null. Did I cut you off in traffic or something?

Comment: Think he meant the nullable type `datetime??`.  Either way I don't care much for either answer.  I much prefer the `C# is npt PHP` comment made earlier :).

Comment: Feel free to disagree. I didn't cut you off either; somehow you requested me to clarify. This I did.