# VB.NET equivalent of C# object initializer of an anonymous type

Tags: c#, vb.net, types, initialization

I'm  not experienced with advanced features of .NET type system. I cannot find out of what type is **zz** (what can be written instead of **var**. Or is **var** the best choice here?)

```csharp
string foo = "Bar";
int cool = 2;
var zz = new { foo, cool };    // Watches show this is Anonymous Type
```

but most importantly, how the equivalent can be achieved in VB.NET code (this is what I actually need).

```vb
Dim Foo As String = "Bar"
Dim Cool As Integer = 2
Dim zz = {Foo, Cool}    'This is not an equivalent of above, I'm getting an array
```

I have searched several C# sources, used code watches and learned about how **zz** looks internally but I'm unable to make next step.

(The purpose of my effort is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640223/is-it-possible-to-include-a-c-sharp-variable-in-a-string-variable-without-using) in VB.NET.)

Comment: NOTE: This question is about **object initializer of an anonymous type**. If instead, you are looking for how to initialize properties, for an **existing class**, then you want to make [**object initializer of a named type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/object-initializers-named-and-anonymous-types).  E.g. `New Customer With {.Name = "Terry Adams", .City = "Louisville"}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code would not even compile with `OPTION STRICT` set to ON which is highly recommended. No type can be derived from `String` + `Int32`. It would compile if you want an `Object()`:

```
Dim zz As Object() = {Foo, Cool}
```

But you want  to create an anonymous type, use `New With`:

```
Dim zz = New With {Foo, Cool}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx

---

With .NET 4.7 and Visual Basic 2017 you can also use `ValueTuples` with names:

```
Dim zz = (FooName:=foo, CoolName:=cool)
```

Now you can access the tuple items by name:

```
int cool = zz.CoolName;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples

Comment: This actually works, I overlooked simple `With {...}` I was already using elsewhere. From what you write I understand that the type cannot be narrowed any further. My attempt was to make string formatter refferring directly to variable names in its format string – and now it works great. But sacrificing my favourite `Option Strict On` – I'll consider twice whether I really want to continue with the above approach.

Comment: If you set `OPTION INFER ON` you can use anonymous types and don´t have to sacrifice `OPTION STRICT ON`

Comment: @NePh: but `OPTION INFER ON` (which i also recommend) doesn't prevent you from a compiler error if you try: `Dim zz = {Foo, Cool}`. Both types are "incompatible". So the error forces you to think twice what you want.

Comment: @miroxlav: i'm not sure if i'd understood your requirement. Can't you use `String.Format` which allows object or can't you use `ToString` to convert all to strings?

Comment: @TimSchmelter and @NePh – you already helped me greatly to achieve what I need. In some cases I would like to avoid format strings like `"{0},{1}"` and use actual variables instead like `"{Foo},{Cool}"` in format string. I'm not sure whether unifying all using `.ToString()` will help in this case, because as I shown I'd like to preserve variable names to use in my compiler extension: `"{Foo},{Cool}".ExpandVars(New With {Foo, Cool})`.  We can discuss overall suitability of ExpandVars approach but for creation of SQL I think it is easier and safer to read/maintain than `SELECT {0} FROM {1}`.

Comment: C# anonymous type properties are all readonly, so in VB you would need to specify 'Key' for all properties: Dim zz = New With {Key Foo, Key Cool} to achieve identical behavior as the original C# code.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, thanks for the note. For my purpose of compiler extension, the less keywords, the better so for now I'm sticking with form without `Key` keyword until it works well: `"SELECT {ColumnList} FROM {TableName}".ExpandVars(New With {TableName, ColumnList})`